# Good Tutorial/Plugin for building UIs with ExtJS MVC

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, extjs-mvc

I am a bit new to client-side coding, and am looking for a good plugin/tutorial/demo/example to build UIs with ExtJS-MVC.

Please don't start a debate on other frameworks(jQuery/ext etc.).

Thanks.

Comment: there are a few at www.mutinyworks.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha is used by over two million developers and its great if you use extjs for building RIAs. Please have a look on resources i provided:

1.[Extjs examples](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) has plenty amount of example components which some of them are written in MVC and you may follow their examples.

2.Follow [sencha blog](http://www.sencha.com/blog/) and follow their posts regarding extjs.

3.Read [Api documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) and follow some of MVC tutorials available.

4.Check [sencha learning center's](http://www.sencha.com/learn/) articles and screencasts

5.Subscribe to [devzone articles](http://www.dzone.com/links/search.html?queryextjs) rss feed regarding extjs.

6.Extjs 4 in action will be out sooner or later and you could buy this book while there are plenty of books available for extjs 3.xx and most of content can be applied to extjs 4 with little modification.

7.[Tomatocart](http://www.tomatocart.com/), [Tomatocms](http://www.tomatocms.com/),[qwikioffice](http://qwikioffice.com/) and  [tine20](http://www.tine20.org/) are built using extjs 3.xx and you may check their demo section and download their full package and start learning from them.

There are plenty powerful extjs coders here in stackoverflow and you may ask questions if they arent already answered.